# Have figcaption always be displayed over other figures (z-index)

Tags: css, html

I have multiple images with absolute positioning of which some may overlap. Some images have a caption.

```html
<div id="entry1" class="entry" title="foo" style="position:absolute; top: 75px; left: 50px; z-index: 2;">
  <figure>
  <figcaption style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">Foo</figcaption>
 <img src="img1.png">
  </figure>
</div>
<div id="entry2" class="entry" title="Bar" style="position:absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; z-index: 2;">
  <figure>
  <figcaption style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">Bar</figcaption>
 <img src="img2.png">
  </figure>
</div>
```

It is not important which caption is on top of which caption or which images is on top of which image. However, I want that all figcaptions are always above the images (in terms of z-index) so they are readable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you mean add position:absolute to the <figure> and <figcaption> as well, not only the wrapping divs?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot.

Comment: I put my comments in an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely positioning these items you can use CSS [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control) to stack them.

This will tell the browser what order you want the item layers to display on the page, higher numbers will be placed *over* layers with lower `z-index` values.